# Signed Magnitude Binary number to Hexadecimal

Tags: binary, number-systems

I can't find too much about this by myself when googling and I am confused overall. So I decided to ask here.

So I'm trying to convert a Signed Magnitude Binary number to Hexadecimal.

Lets take 111011. So being that it is signed, I know that the leftmost bit will signify a negative sign (-ve). And the "11011" part is 27. So that number would be -27 in base-10.

But how would you represent that in hex? How do negative signs work in hex?

Answer (score 1):

Negative signs work *exactly* the same way in hexadecimal as they do in decimal: simply put $-$ before the number. In your case, $-27_{10}=-\rm{1B}_{16}$.

Sign-and-magnitude notation is peculiar because there exists a representation of negative zero. Because of this, and the gate cost of implementing circuitry working with this format, we do not use it often, instead preferring twos-complement (which has no negative zero). A brief survey of digital representations of negative numbers can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).